# Existem tags principais sem ser no meta?

Tags: suporte, tags

Existem tags principais no SO, no mesmo esquema que aqui no meta, ou a ordem de tags não importa?

Comment: Você quer dizer, tipo as `suporte`, `debate`, etc aqui do Meta?

Comment: isso... não importa a ordem das tags no site principal, certo?

Comment: Não. No site principal todas as tags são "iguais" e nenhuma é obrigatória - mas é obrigatória ter uma. Entendeu? `:D`

Comment: E elas ficam ordenadas pela quantidade total da tag no site todo.

Comment: OK. Só pra confirmar. Postei uma pergunta e as tags foram trocadas de ordem, agora vejo porque :)

Comment: Suponho que no título da pergunta (fora do meta) o título fique com o prefixo da tag com maior numero de perguntas, então posso arriscar a dizer que nas perguntas existe sim uma tag principal que é a tag com maior numero de perguntas vinculadas (não tenho certeza se é isto que influencia pra tag aparece no prefixo do titulo da página).